# Loading animated images with devIL

Tags: c, image-processing, devil

Is this code sample correct? Why do some of _data have the same values? How can i get pointers to every animation frame contained in gif image?

```
_num = ilGetInteger(IL_NUM_IMAGES)+1;

for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++)
{
    ilActiveImage(i);
    _data.push_back(ilGetData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is very weak at this point. Correct code should be

```
num = ilGetInteger(IL_NUM_IMAGES);
for(int i = 0; i != num; ++i) {
    ilBindImage(your_image_id);
    ilActiveImage(i + 1);   // counts from 1
    // do something with ilGetData()
}
```

No doc seems to say that re-binding before each `ilActiveImage` is required, but it is.

Comment: thank you, now it works! But why does IL load GIFs upside down? It's okay with BMPs and PNGs though.